# Indiasearcher.in malware removal assistance

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, malware, malware-removal

**Operating system**: Windows 7
**Architecture**: 32 bit
**Antivirus software and on-demand scanners on this system** : 
ESET smart security
Malwarebytes Antimalware
Spybot Search and Destroy

**Date and how issue started:** 
I don't remember how it started, but when I boot into my Windows OS, A default browser (Chrome) Window opened with indiasearcher.in/fsquirt.exe page.

If I close the browser, "Windows explorer has stopped working" message box appears and system becomes very slow. I couldn't open control panel as well as windows update and other control panel items.

I somehow managed to boot into safe mode with networking and cleaned with Malwarebytes as well as Spybot S&D. I had Bitdefender IS 2013 at that time and also performed a scan with it. I think I succeeded partially.

**Current issues and symptoms:** 
Right now, "Windows explorer has stopped working" no longer appears, but still A browser windows opens at startup. I installed ESET smart security now and performed scan again. It cleaned two .js files JS/Kryptik.ALI Trojan, but my issue still persists.

Any ideas how to identify which process initiates the browser launch during startup?

Comment: as silly has it seems, could you check that it hasn't changed your browser short cut? If it was firefox, I'd also reset it to default settings, but I have no clue if it works on chrome.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I think malware is trying to launch whichever the default browser is. I'm not sure how to detect which process in my system us helping it during startup...

Comment: Guess I've figured out the process which helps the malware.

It is "explorer.exe". I now tried to kill process from task manager and tried to open a new task "explorer" in task manager. Voila. Google chrome opened with fsquirt.exe web page.

Now how do I stop this?